# Probability and expected value of a continuous variable in the finite interval

Tags: probability, continuous-data, distributions

Let's consider a continuous random variable $X$ following normal PDF $f(x)$ and we know the interval of population of this variable, say, $X\in[-4,4]$

Then, the expected value is simply $\int_{-4}^{4}Xf(x)dx$, but
what is the probability of population $[-4,4]$? **It should be one.**

But by the definition of normal PDF, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$
which implies $\int_{-4}^{4}f(x)dx<1$ even though the population is $[-4,4]$.

What happened here?

Comment: What do you mean by "population of this variable"?  A normal random variable can take any real value, and is not limited to any finite interval.  Are you perhaps thinking of the observed range of values from (draws of) several independent and identically distributed normal random variables?  That is a different beast.

Comment: Yes, first I thought like you, but there are many situations, for example, in a water tank on the top of some building, the amount of water in it can have mean and variance following normal distribution depending on the water usage of residents. In this case, the amount of water can be infinite.

Comment: Sorry for typo!. the amount of water CAN NOT be INFINITE

Comment: Well, then in such case, the distribution is not normal. Perhaps it could be a truncated normal, which has one or more ends chopped off, and the density increased in the portion which is not chopped off.

Comment: Thanks, but in many practices we just assume normal pdf not a truncated normal pdf. If there is some data set that we can know the finite interval of a population, can we never use normal pdf or some other familiar pdf?

Comment: If the possible values are restricted to a finite interval, it can not be exactly normally distributed. Depending on the parameters and the interval, it may be that the probability of a normal being outside the interval is so low that it can essentially be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Your last statement is not entirely correct. If X only has support on [-4, 4] (as you suggested) then for anything outside of those bounds, it equals 0. You can think of it as:

$1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-4}f(x)dx  + \int_{-4}^{4}f(x)dx  + \int_{4}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 0 + \int_{-4}^{4}f(x)dx + 0 = 1$

Comment: I am assuming $f(x)$ normal pdf.

Comment: Per my comment above, you (kurtkim) are making contradictory assumptions.

Comment: Right - it can only be a truncated normal if it lives between -4 and 4 and follows a normal distribution.